# Given a meromorphic function (via its Laurent series), how to obtain the (Taylor series of the) two holomorphic functions it is the quotient of?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, convolution, laurent-series

Since any meromorphic function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ can be expressed as the quotient of two entire functions, i.e. $f(z) = \frac{n(z)}{d(z)}$ where the zeros of the denominator $d(z)$ are $f$'s singularities, I was wondering how to obtain the latters' Taylor coefficients given the former's Laurent series, i.e.

given the $f_k$ in $f(z) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_k z^k$ (the expansion is centered around zero for simplicity), how to obtain the $n_k, d_k$ of $m_k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty m_kz^k, (m\in\{n,d\})$?

Sure enough one can rearrange the fraction to obtain
$$\begin{align}
  d(z)\cdot f(z) &\stackrel!= n(z)
\\\Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty d_l f_{k-l} \right)z^k &\stackrel!= \sum_{k=0}^\infty n_k z^k
\\\Rightarrow \sum_{l=0}^\infty d_l f_{k-l} &= \begin{cases} 0 & k<0 \\ n_k & k\ge 0\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
i.e. a discrete convolution. But how to solve for the $d_k, n_k$? Are they unique (up to multiplication by a non-vanishing entire function as mrf and Daniel Fischer pointed out)? While the Laurent series does not necessarily converge on all of $\mathbb C$, $n(z), d(z)$ being entire should do so.

Comment: $n$ and $d$ are not uniquely determined. You can multiply and divide by any non-vanishing entire function, i.e. by $e^g$ for any entire $g$. This operation will change the Taylor coefficients of $n$ and $d$.

Comment: They are not unique. You can always multiply $n$ and $d$ by the same nowhere vanishing entire function, say $\exp(z^m)$ to get something that doesn't affect the first $m$ coefficients of $n$ or $d$.

Comment: Good point. Ok, so the question should be modified to "up to a never-vanishing entire function" (which includes constant factors of course...)

Comment: Hm, this means quite an ambiguity. I wonder if there is some "minimum $e$-ishness" one could require...